# Tensorflow inception retraining : bottleneck files creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow, deep-learning, bazel

I'm following [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) to retrain the inception model adapted to my own problem.
I have about 50 000 images in around 100 folders / categories.

Running this

`bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain`

`bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir /path/to/root_folder_name`

on Amazon EC2 g2.2xlarge I was hoping that the full process would be quite fast (faster than on my laptop) but the bottleneck files creation takes a long time.
Assuming it's already been 2 hours and only 800 files have been created, I will need more than 5 days (!!) to just create the files...

Is it supposed to be faster than this rythm ( ~ 400 bottleneck files created / hour) because of the GPU ?

How could I make the process faster ?

Comment: 23 hours later, 12 000 images have been analyzed. Will I really have to wait 5 days ?

Comment: GPUs should make this faster, yes, but you have a lot of images. Are you sure tensorflow is recognizing the GPU? Regardless, you can parallelize this on many machines as the bottleneck values depend only on the images.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos in fact this was the case : GPU not recognized by bazel. I spent the whole day to understand how to fix this and after running through some issues and solutions (thanks github tensorflow !) I managed to do it. Now the ruthm is 400 images per minutes instead of per hour !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to my question.

Bazel was working without GPU support. To solve this, I modified files regarding these issues :

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1066
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2143
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1157

and ran

`TF_UNOFFICIAL_SETTING=1 ./configure`

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain --verbose_failures`

`bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/Images/`

At the end of the day, the process was a lot faster (500 images / second) and the training itself was also done with the GPU !

Comment: I got a quick question, i am very new to Tensorflow, before i run bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/Images/   I think i suppose to build the retrainer with bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain..... but just building the retrainer has taken me over 30 mins.....does it suppose to take that long?Or is it supposed to be longer?